# Unable to add parameters for reporting in Firebase analytics

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, reporting, firebase-analytics

I have an Event called `Ecommerce_purchase`, when I try to add parameter for reporting from analytics dashboard of *Firebase*, it gives me two errors:

1. Internal error ! try again (In Red in center)
2. One or more parameters have not been registered! try again! (right top corner)

Comment: have you tried sending some debug ecommerce_purchase events yet?

Comment: Can you check whether it's working now? Yesterday I wrote in Firebase support, and they fixed the problem on their side. Today it's works.

Answer (score 1):

Did you change parameters for this event? When you add/remove parameters for an event, you may get this error.

Recently, I did a tidy up for Firebase Analytics of my app. Some events' names were kept but added/removed some parameters. I then started getting this internal error. When Firebase receives one set of parameters for one event from one user and a different set of parameters from another user, it gets confused.

When you want to change parameters for an event, I suggest you change the event name as well to avoid the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Problem gets solved when you try adding parameters using incognito window of chrome .